# JS & HTML - place on html on which the JS script will appear

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to JS.

I want to have my html page stay the same when JS text will be appearing in one exact place without starting from blank page.

I trigger JS function via button on HTML, function in HTML:

```
function match () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        player_hp -= monster_dmg
        monster_hp -= player_dmg
        if (player_hp<=0) {
            document.write("\nPlayer dies!")
            menu();
            return;
        }
        if (monster_hp<=0) {
            document.write("\nPlayer wins!")
            menu();
            return;
        }
        if (fight=1) {
            document.write("\nPlayer hp:" + player_hp)
            document.write("\nMonster hp:" + monster_hp)
            document.write("\n");
            match()
        }
    }, interval)
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you have to manipulate the DOM instead of just writing to the document. Longer answer: this is the basic concept of all SPAs, there are quite a few SPA frameworks out there that enable you to build complex applications based on this. But at least you should check JQuery, which is quite a handy tool in manipulating the DOM. So, first start to learn what is the DOM is, and how you can touch it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: there is no html in what you show. you are just writing plain text. if you want some layout, you should think of how you want it (mostly css) and then use your JS to fill the places with your text. As said by ZorgoZ DOM manipulation is needed. But for your need, write your own js rather than learning a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to handle this is to simply create a `<div>` or a `<span>` element that has an ID attribute like this:

`<div id="status"> </div>`

Now you can access this element by using the Javascript method

`document.querySelector("#status")`  and then use the innerHTML function of that element to change the internal content. You can even place the `document.querySelector` function into a convenient function which I have named `send_status()`

Here's  the whole thing

```js
/* default values */
var player_hp = 300;
var monster_dmg = 30;
var monster_hp = 200;
var interval = 500;
var player_dmg = 50;
match();


/* heres a function that will replace your document.write()  functions */
function send_status(message) {
  document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = message;
}

function match() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    player_hp -= monster_dmg
    monster_hp -= player_dmg
    if (player_hp <= 0) {
      send_status("\nPlayer dies!") // replaced document.write with send_status
      menu();
      return;
    }
    if (monster_hp <= 0) {
      send_status("\nPlayer wins!")
      menu();
      return;
    }
    if (fight = 1) {
      send_status("\nPlayer hp:" + player_hp)
      send_status("\nMonster hp:" + monster_hp)
      send_status("\n");
      match()
    }
  }, interval)
}

function menu() {}
```

```css
#game {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#status {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">Game Goes Here</div>

<!-- here is your status area -->
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: I cannot express my gratitude! This solution is greater than I could imagine. Thank you!

PS: That monster_dmg is a lot too much, hahha :D

Comment: ideally you want to probably change all of those globals into a more flexible object-based system. There are many reasons for this (instead of using monster_dmg , create a "monster object"  that has a "damage" property and a function named "attack"  which can then be used to tell your "player" object to "lose hp  and die if necessary"  rather than having many global vars..   google  'javascript objects' for more info

Answer (score 0):

You should create a results `div`, in which will be shown the match result.
Just add `<div id="match_results"></div>` in your HTML code.

And replace all yours `document.write()` for 
`document.getElementById('match_results').innerHTML += "<br>Player wins!"`

This command is appending content in the element with ID `match_results`.

You should use `<br>` instead of `\n` because it is the proper way to break line in HTML code.